# Extract lines that follow a pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I'm looking to extract all lines that begins with `Start` and its next line ends with `***`.

Appreciate any help.

**Example**:

```
*********************************************
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-2359]
*********************************************
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-2987]
Available
Printing records
Moving to output file
*********************************************
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-1539]
*********************************************
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-4527]
Available
Printing records
Moving to output file
*********************************************
```

**Desired Output**:

```
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-2359]
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-1539]
```

I tried:

```sh
awk '/Start*/ {p=1;print;next} /$**/ && p {p=0;print} p' test
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried with no luck

awk '/Start*/ {p=1;print;next}  /$\*\*/ && p {p=0;print} p' test

Comment: Grep might be useful in this situation i.e. `grep -B1 '^\*\*\*' file | grep '^Start'`

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. With `tac` + `awk` approach here.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk '
/^\*/{
  count=""
  found=1
  next
}
found && ++count==1 && /^Start/{
  print
  found=""
}
' | tac
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
tac Input_file |                   ##Using tac wit Input_file to print contents in reverse order and send it to awk command.
awk '                              ##Starting awk program here which reads tac output as an Input here.
/^\*/{                             ##Checking condition if line starts from * then do following.
  count=""                         ##Nullifying count here.
  found=1                          ##Setting found as 1 here.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found && ++count==1 && /^Start/{   ##Checking if found is SET and count is 1 and line starts with Start then do following.
  print                            ##Printing current line here.
  found=""                         ##Nullifying found here.
}
' | tac                            ##Sending awk program output as an input to tac to get output in exact order.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '(index($0,"***")==1) && (p1=="Start"){print p0} {p1=$1; p0=$0}' file
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-2359]
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-1539]
```

For every line after the first, `p1` and `p0` contain the values of `$1` and `$0` from the previous line read. So when the current line starts with 3 `*`s and the `$1` from the previous line (`p1`) was `Start` then it prints the `$0` from the previous line (`p0`).

With respect to the regexps in your question:

- `Start*` means `Star` followed by `t` repeated 0 or more times.
- `$**` contains back-to-back regexp repetition characters (`*`) and so is undefined behavior per POSIX and so any tool can do whatever it likes with it. Some will report it, some will silently ignore one of the *s, others could do anything else. The $ at the start is an end-of-string indication which matches the end of the current input so having any *s after it doesn't make sense but AFAIK it's not technically invalid.

Comment: I don't understand how `awk` processes the data in this case. It only gives as result two lines and not four lines: the four starting with the same characters, `Start`, and also preceded with asterisks.

Comment: @CarlosPascual the task is to print lines that start with `Start` and are **succeeded** by the line with asterisks, not **preceded** by it. I added an explanation, if it's still not clear let me know.

Comment: OK, Understood: `p1 and p0 contain the values of $1 and $0 from the previous line read.` I didn't see `the previous line`. Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` should work:

```sh
awk 'p != "" && /^\*{3}/ {print p} {p = ($1 == "Start" ? $0 : "")}' file

Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-2359]
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-1539]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/^Start/!d;N;/\*\{3\}$/P;D' file
```

```
pcregrep -Mo1 '^(Start.*)\n.*\*{3}$' file
```

`Start*` would match `Star` or `Startttt` anywhere in a string. The regex to match `Start` at the beginning of a string is `^Start`.

`$**` is not a useful RE - `*` should not be repeated like that. [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) leaves the behaviour undefined, with GNU sed reporting it as `Invalid preceding regular expression`. `\*\{3\}$` (or equivalent) will match a string ending with three asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way using GNU `AWK`, let `file.txt` content be

```
*********************************************
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-2359]
*********************************************
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-2987]
Available
Printing records
Moving to output file
*********************************************
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-1539]
*********************************************
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-4527]
Available
Printing records
Moving to output file
*********************************************
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n?[*]+\n";FS="\n"}($NF~/^Start/)' file.txt
```

output

```
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-2359]
Start the extract for customer_id [XXXX-1539]
```

Explanation: I instructed `AWK` to treat content between lines with `*` as rows and lines in content as fields. To attain such effect I set row separator (`RS`) to one or more `*` followed by newline (`\n`) with `\n` optionally at begin (without that first `*********************************************` would not be detected corretly) and `FS` to newline (`\n`). Then I check if last field i.e. line starts with `Start`. DISCLAIMER: this solution assumes that last line of your file is always like `[*]+` it might fail if it is not.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^\*\*\*/{g;/^Start/p};h' file
```

Turn off implicit printing.

If the current line begins `***`, replace it by the previous line stored in the hold space and if that line begins `Start` print that line.

In all cases, store the current line in the hold space.

Another couple of solutions:

```
sed -n 'N;/^Start.*\n\*\*\*/P;D' file
```

or:

```
sed -n 'N;/^Start/{/^\*\*\*/MP};D' file
```

Both open a 2 line window and print the first of those lines if it begins `Start` and the second begins `***`.

The second solution uses the `M` flag to match the `***` at the start of a line, as there are only 2 such lines and the first begins `Start` the criteria for the both matches is met.